# ORM tools/framework regarding mongodb for Java

Tags: java, mongodb, orm, maven

is there any ORM tool/framework for mongoDB with java and also support maven, so that it will be helpful to apply constraints, use of cursers in database operations?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are some. Start reading:

http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Java+Language+Center

As for maven support,  just look up libraries in mvnrepository.com ( most of them will be there )

Answer (score 2):

This is what you need:
http://www.infoq.com/articles/mongodb-java-orm-bcd
It is maven-based.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 2):

See this presenation on slide share http://www.slideshare.net/mongodb/java-persistence-frameworks-for-mongodb

Answer (score 0):

To work with Mongo Db at grass root level  I found http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/05/29/mongodb-selectqueryfind-documents-examples/ link very helpful

Answer (score 0):

try [MongoDBExecutor](https://cdn.rawgit.com/landawn/AbacusUtil/master/docs/MongoCollectionExecutor_view.html). It will definitely increase the productivity of development. Here is simple sample about CRUD:

```
   @Test
   public void test_crud_by_id() {
       Account account = createAccount();
       account.setId(ObjectId.get().toString());

       // create
       collExecutor.insert(account);

       // read
       Account dbAccount = collExecutor.get(Account.class, account.getId());

       // update
       dbAccount.setFirstName("newFirstName");
       collExecutor.update(dbAccount.getId(), N.asMap(FIRST_NAME, dbAccount.getFirstName()));

       // delete
       collExecutor.delete(dbAccount.getId());

       // check
       assertFalse(collExecutor.exists(dbAccount.getId()));
   }
```

Declaration: I'm the developer of AbacusUtil

Answer (score 0):

You can use [morphia](http://morphiaorg.github.io/morphia/).

It is a wrapper over mongo-java-driver and works well in the production environment. It is well documented and supports raw queries as well.

Also, well [SO community support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/morphia)